# Unable to make a MySQL connection through Perl when called in a PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, perl

I'm creating a connection to a MySQL database within a Perl script, called by a PHP script. Here are the 2 scripts:

**Perl:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# script name = MyCode.pl
use DBI;
my $data_source = q/dbi:mysql:name:localhost/;
my $user = q/myname/;
my $pwd = q/pword/;

print "before...\n";
# Connect!
$dbhandle= DBI->connect($data_source,$user,$pwd) or die "can't connect
       $data_source: $DBI::errstr \n";
print "...after \n";
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
 // script name = Test.php
 $myResult=shell_exec("perl /path/MyCode.pl");
 echo $myResult;
?>
```

---

When executed on the command line, Test.php prints "before..." and "...after" and the DB connection is indeed established within the Perl code. However, when Test.php is executed from my (Chrome) browser, all that prints is "before..." and no connection is made. And *no* error message is displayed.

Why is there success on the command line but not from a web server?

Comment: Good question. Curious why you would do it this way?

Comment: When it works on the command line and not in a browser, I always go to permissions first. Does your web server (apache?) have permission to run perl and permission to access /path/MyCode.pl?

Comment: I have a 'backend' routine written in Perl that simulates a process for one of my business clients. Things have evolved where I needed a

Comment: (sorry hit return) needed a 'frontend' piece to allow the client to easily communicate with the backend. And so I wrote a php frontend.

Comment: @MikeP Off-topic, but you can edit comments within the first five minutes of posting them.

Comment: @kainaw - yes permissions are all chmod 755.

Comment: btw since "before..." is displayed on the browser, I know the Perl code is being executed. The problem spot is apparently the 'DBI->connect' line.

Comment: Try change `or die` with `or print`.

Comment: Based on comments in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php#78506), it appears that `shell_exec` doesn't capture stderr. Check your web server's error logs...there should be a detailed message about why `connect` is failing.

Comment: Changing to 'or print' did not help. This is all taking place on a hosted account (godaddy) and so I don't think I have access to error logs.

Comment: Can you confirm your data_source format? It is differ than what is mentioned in the manual : `$dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=$database;host=$hostname;port=$port";`

Comment: @tivn Tried the format you describe; it again works command-line but not via browser.

Comment: By any chance do you have more than one perl installed?

Comment: that's the guess from @ThisSuitIsBlackNot...command line and webserver using different versions...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, PHP `shell_exec()` function doesn't capture STDERR.

To debug your code, you can add a `2>&1` at the end of system command to redirect STDERR to **STDOUT**:

```
$myResult = shell_exec("perl /path/script.pl 2>&1");
```

Also, you can setup the DBI module to **die** if some error occurs at runtime:

```
$dbh = DBI->connect($data_source,$user, $pwd, { RaiseError => 1, PrintError => 0}) or die $DBI::errstr;
```

Comment: Well that makes things a lot clearer! Now I see the error message:   install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't locate DBD/mysql.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at (eval 4) line 3. Perhaps the DBD::mysql perl module hasn't been fully installed, or perhaps the capitalisation of 'mysql' isn't right. Available drivers: DBM, ExampleP, File, Gofer, Proxy, SQLite, Sponge. at /home....

Comment: You don't need the `or die` following the `connect` if `RaiseError` is on. Also, `PrintError` is redundant if you're already using `RaiseError`.

Comment: @MikeP The webserver user may be running a different `perl` than you did on the command line. Try passing the full path in `shell_exec`.

Comment: On this (godaddy) hosted site I don't know the part of the path that resides above /home/myUserName/...to me it appears / is at the top...

Comment: You probably set PERL5LIB before executing from the command line

Comment: yes:    echo $PERL5LIB  shows   /home/myUserName/perl5/lib/perl5

Comment: OK thanks for all this great help. Problem fixed...I needed correct path specification: this is done (on godaddy) by using:    use cPanelUserConfig in the Perl script to access the DMD::mysql module that I installed.

Comment: @MikeP Excellent! Please put that in an answer so it can be preserved for all time, just in case another godaddy user has the same problem down the road.

Answer (score 1):

Problem fixed...I needed correct path specification: this is done (on godaddy) by using:

```
use cPanelUserConfig;
```

in the Perl script to access the DBD::mysql module that I installed.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess: from PHP you execute it with "perl /path/MyCode.pl"

The shell opened by Apache are under different user than yours and that user does not perl in it path.

Try using Perl from full path: "/full/path/to/perl /path/MyCode.pl"

FYI: Executing script with perl "scriptname" is not a good practice. Instead define a full path in to your Perl in the shebang and always start your script using the full path. This way you could avoid errors like this.

Regards,
Andras